# Shorter terms for two question types

Tags: single-word-requests, terminology

I am writing a program to scrape questions from a online Stanford-Binet Test website, specifically this series of urls: https://stanfordbinettest.com/quiz/full-quiz/question/#, where # stands for an integer between 1 and 100 (inclusive).

There are 100 questions in total, the test has a time limit of 24 minutes or 1440 seconds, and the questions appear in random order each time the quiz is taken. That's 14.4 seconds for each question, and it's too short for me to work out the answers on average, so I am trying to scrape the questions and find the answers without the time limit.

There are two question types that I have encountered so far, one provides a set of a few predetermined choices to choose from, with the right answer being one of the choices. The other provides a blank input box that accepts keyboard input, and you are supposed to fill in the right answer.

I need terms for the two classification of questions. I know I can call the first multiple-choice questions and the other fill-in-the-blank questions, but these words are too long and cumbersome in my opinion, I want one-word concise terminology for the classifications fit to put into programs.

Comment: Your question is way too long for what it's asking. You can comfortably delete the first two paragraphs and just ask: "What are short names for multiple-choice questions and questions where you write your own answer."

Comment: Is scraping similar in some way to borrowing, taking, or stealing? Free choice answer.

Comment: Multiple choice is commonly abbreviated MC or MCQ. A Cloze test is one type of fill-in-the-blanks although normally used for language learning; they are sometimes jokingly compared to Mad Libs, which also have a fill-the-blank format. If you're using the name internally/for your own use, you can choose what you like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple test question types. They don't have standard single word names but you can pick whatever you like:

- [Multiple choice](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_choice): can be shortened to "*choice*", "*MCQ*", "objective"
- [Free response](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_response): "*free*", "*text*", "*essay*"
- [Completion type](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Test_(assessment)#Completion_type): "*completion*", "*blank*", "*fill*"

There are [other types](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Test_(assessment)#Written_tests) which you may be interested in.

Comment: I guess I will use 'choice' and 'completion' then.